# Broken Splash boot screen with significant performance and freezing issues

Tags: boot, 14.04, virtualbox

okay heres the story and yes this is important becauses its what was the last thing i did before this madness

watched a youtube video which ive now flagged and reported but he basically instructed us to su virtualbox into the system i dont know what i did all i did was follow directions

now im plagued with no ubuntu purple boot screen it goes straight to a black screen filled with letters

and im experiencing more lag and freezing than i ever have before  this is not from an upgrade ive had 14.04 for about a month before this happened im at a loss for what my routes are it was all i could do to remove the superblocks just to get back into my desktop

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to start off:
1) can you get a terminal to open? (ctrl+alt+F3) 
2) if so, at the command line, type either:

sudo apt-get install -f

OR

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a

1st option is fairly quick, 2nd option could take some time, your choice, they both repair system dependencies.
source: http://www.unixmen.com/reinstall-ubuntu-with-one-command/

2) if you can't get into a terminal:
3) make a boot-disk(if you already have one with your current version on it, great)
4) boot the computer up, with usb(or cd, depending on what media you have) set as the 1st boot option.
5) click install Ubuntu, follow instructions until it asks what sort of install you want.
6) select repair current installation

The above *should* resolve your problems. If it does, I would uninstall virtualbox until you're a bit more familiar with the system, but to each their own.

sudo apt-get remove virtualbox

Comment: completely removed virtualbox this pc cannot handle the demands but when i finally build my custom pc i will seek a proper install method but im able to enter my desktop already did another method with the live cd to be able to boot into my desktop ill try your method thanks for the reply sorry to take solong to reply kinda busy with work

Answer (score 0):

- Stopping ClamAV virus database updater freshclam                      [ OK ]

  - Starting ClamAV virus database updater freshclam                      [ OK ] 
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 1: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 2: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [gnome_session]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 7: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 8: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 9: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: [general_ubuntu]: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 12: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: backend: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: integration: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: plugin_list_autosort: not found
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/compiz.config: profile: not found

this is the end of option two, is this normal or is this bad?

Comment: Is this another question? or an answer to previous? Either way, the above shows there is an issue with your compiz install. Run from command line:  
sudo apt-get -f install compiz

Comment: Welp tried to get to repair install on live cd and ended up corrupting my current installation so now im without any ubuntu trying to get online to download fedora and move away from this crap hole of an operating system